# Running bundler under root - git://github.com/feedbin/activerecord-import.git (at b7851b1) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, chef-infra

I use chef to run bundle.

```
bash "feedbin_bundle" do
   cwd "/home/ubuntu/workspace/frontend"
   user "root"
   group "root"
   code <<-EOH
     bundle install
   EOH
end
```

Now I want to run the below as ubuntu user:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/workspace/frontend$ rake db:setup
'git://github.com/feedbin/activerecord-import.git (at b7851b1) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

If I run as root all is well.  How to I avoid the above error and run rake db:setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your gems are installed for the user `root`, in the `~root/.gems` directory. You don't want this. You have three possibilities:

- Install gems system-wide, by tweaking the `/etc/gemrc` file
- Install gems as the user who will run the application
- The "clean" solution: install gems in a `vendor` subdirectory: `bundle install --path=vendor/`. This way, the gems are installed only for the project, and will not conflict with other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `bundle install` as `ubuntu`, the same user you want to use to run your program.